# OData Sign-in from Excel

Tags: excel, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services, azure-web-roles

We have a windows azure cloud service for OData feed. It is developed as WCF service and deployed as web role.
When opened the OData Service from web browser, the login page appears and able to provide credentials and get authenticated. The OData feed is then accessible.
When opened in Excel using 'From OData Data Feed' option in 'Data' Menu, service unable to consume credentials.
Is there a different way of implementing security if OData need to be made available for Excel client?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Excel 2013. This should be as easy as entering your authentication credentials within the excel wizard for adding OData feeds.

There is a tutorial for the wizard in this [blog](http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/consuming-odata-feeds-from-excel-services-2013-in-powerpivot/).

Comment: the WCF service is not considering the credentials provided through that wizard. But web browser credentials working.